# Ajax, refresh table rows on new additions

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, celery

I'm working on a Django project that runs a background task every time a form is submitted. It takes roughly 2sec to complete each task, when completed, the results are saved, ajax is supposed to perform page refresh but not the whole page, and what I have so far is:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        setInterval('location.reload()', 10000);
    }
})
```

It works as intended, but it's wrong. I have rather limited experience with js. However, I'd like to refresh only the newly added row(s) in the table. I came across `jquery` `.load()` but I've been staring for a while now, please any help?

EDIT:

So js/ajax is just responsible for page refresh on a specific row like so

| id | name | date | log | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | task1 | today | pending... | pending... |

Each row has a corresponding table in the database, on task completion log and status are no longer pending but updated with DB objects.

Django handles form validation and submission on another page which gets redirected to this one with the tabular result, the user waits for a few sec and boom, ajax drops the magic.

Comment: can you add snippet of your code

Comment: or add in your above code above setinterval 'event.preventdefault();' and check that it is work. becuase form submit automatically happened and this code will prevent from above code

Comment: Is having an endpoint to get only the table data an option? so you make that query and do a table.html(result) with table your dom element and result what ever your view returns